Remove Directories after Loop
Hoping someone with true unix knowledge can help with what will inevitably be something straightforward, but I can't seem to fumble my way through.
I'm just wanting to remove the $ORIG_DIR once the loop has run through a single and remove the $ALAC_DIR if the original files are .mp3 and it's finished the loop?
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "${dirs[0]}")"; pwd)/$(basename "${dirs[0]}")"
SOURCE_DIR=$(dirname "$SOURCE_DIR/temp") # this fixes . and ./
HIRES_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "${dirs[1]}")"; pwd)/$(basename "${dirs[1]}")"
HIRES_DIR=$(dirname "$HIRES_DIR/temp") # this fixes . and ./
LORES_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "${dirs[2]}")"; pwd)/$(basename "${dirs[2]}")"
LORES_DIR=$(dirname "$LORES_DIR/temp") # this fixes . and ./
find "$SOURCE_DIR" \( -iname '*.flac' -or -iname '*.mp3' \) -type f -print | while read -r FILE
do
  ORIG_DIR=$(dirname "$FILE") 
  BASE=$(basename "$FILE") 
  BASE=${BASE%.*} 
  AAC_DIR=${ORIG_DIR/$SOURCE_DIR/$LORES_DIR}
  ALAC_DIR=${ORIG_DIR/$SOURCE_DIR/$HIRES_DIR}
  mkdir -p "$AAC_DIR" "$ALAC_DIR"
  AAC_FILE="$AAC_DIR/$BASE.m4a"
  ALAC_FILE="$ALAC_DIR/$BASE.m4a"
  if [[ (! -f "$AAC_FILE" && $FILE == *.flac) ]]; then
    ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$FILE" -c:v copy -b:a 256k -c:a aac "$AAC_FILE" </dev/null &&
    ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$FILE" -c:v copy -c:a alac "$ALAC_FILE" </dev/null
  elif [[ (! -f "$AAC_FILE" && $FILE == *.mp3) ]]; then
    ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$FILE" -c:v copy -b:a 256k -c:a aac "$AAC_FILE" </dev/null &&
  rmdir "$ALAC_DIR"
  fi
done
rm -rf "$ORIG_DIR"

Placing after the 'done' it doesn't recognise "$ALAC_DIR" or "$ORIG_DIR" as directories any more.  Placing before 'done' it removes the directories before all files have been processed and creates an error...
P.S. The $ALAC_DIR was placed incorrectly and should removed if the original files are mp3's.  The main goal is to have a clean top level original source folder once all conversions have been completed, rather me having to manually maintain the folder.

cmd1 | cmd2 is a subshell context. if you are using bash despite not tagging the questions as such, you can rewrite as cmd2 < <(cmd1)

If you would debug your program with set -x, you would see that the variables are empty.  It is not clear to me what value would you want to see in this variables.ORIG_DIR changes its value on each loop iteration. So you want to remove the value the variable had during its last iteration?

Script is written in bash.
ORIG_DIR is the file path the source file for conversion is held.  So after all files in the directory have been converted, I would like to delete the original folder holding the files.

ORIG_DIR is the file path the source file for conversion is held. : Why then is the value of the variable changed in every loop iteration?  _ I would like to delete the original folder holding the files._ : But wouldn't this also remove the converted files? After all, you try to do a rmdir "$ALAC_DIR". This seems to be the directory holding the result of the conversion.

BTW, all these details you get asked in a comment, should better be answered by updating the question, and not by a comment, since your answers are supposed to clarify what you want to achieve. It would also be helpful if you could sketch a small directory tree before the conversion, and how it should look like after conversion.
